# PHP Mysql Update issue

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having an issue that I can't quite figure out. I have a bit of code that allows a user to pick, let's say, which type of fruit is their favourite. If they've previously selected 'apples' as their favourite and want to change it to 'oranges' - the script performs well.

But if they select 'apples' when they've already selected 'apples' the MYSQL Update call breaks down and returns an error. It's like it won't write over itself with the same data, that the new value has to be unique. I'm at a loss.... Here's the update bit:

```
    // UPDATE THEIR FRUIT SELECTION...
    $q = "UPDATE account SET fav_fruit='" . $row['fruit'] . "' WHERE act_id=$act_id LIMIT 1";       
    $r = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);
    if (mysqli_affected_rows($dbc) == 1) { // If it ran OK.
           echo 'success!';

    } else { 
        echo 'oops!';
    }
```

Again, this works so long as the new selection and what's in the database aren't the same. If they are: I get the oops! error.

Comment: What error? Why do you need `@` before `mysqli_query`?

Comment: the error is nondescript - my own text, not a mysql standard error: "The user could not be updated due to a system error."

Comment: Use of @ to suppress errors is usually frowned upon. It's much better to just set `error_reporting()` in the script or PHP.ini to none.

Comment: Yes, as zerkms has said, remove the @ t, and check what mysqli_query's returning. If it's returning FALSE, then the query failed and `mysqli_error()` will return the error message. Also inspect your `$q` to see what the query string is for one of those "update to same" queries that's not working.

Comment: Hey - took away the @ (error reporting is on) and there's no change. Also - the query works fine when not selecting the same value as what's already in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you need to update a field to contain a value it already contains?
Regardless, this can be fixed by altering the table structure. You need to remove the unique flag from the `fav_fruit` column.

Comment: Is there any reason that you need to update a value to the value already stored?

Comment: Kind of - I mean they need to be able to select different values and change this whenever they need to. If there was a way to basically say - "Hey, you've selected this choice, but here are others" and just leave out the value that's already stored, that'd be cool.

Comment: Temporary solution: How about querying the DB before you insert the new value to check if the value is the one currently stored. This seems unnecessary, though, because does the query need to succeed if the value is already stored?

Comment: That sounds like it should work - I'm trying to put it together real quick to test it...